# jmeter server response time calculation

Tags: jmeter

I'm basically trying to calculate in **JMeter 5.1** the server processing time for a HTTP request. I've read the JMeter documentation (specially https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) to know more about `Elapsed time`, `Latency` and `Connect time`.

Let's say I have a test plan with one thread which does **successively** 3 identical HTTP requests to one server. The thing is that for the first request, `Connect time` is (obviously) not equal to 0, but it is for second and third request.

However, from my understanding, `Latency` includes `Connect time`, hence for my first request, the `Latency` is always (much) larger than for the second and third request, and it does not reflect the time spent waiting (server processing time) for this first request.

Can I assume that, if I substract the `Connect time` from the `Latency` (`Latency` - `Connect time`), it gives me a meaningfull value of the server processing time (+ download content time maybe?)

Answer (score 0):

See w3c time-taken HTTP request log field.   Just turn this on and post process the HTTP request logs at the end of your test.  You will have the complete processing time for each individual request.

Comment: I am not sure to properly understand. Does your suggestion requires to change/add configuration on server side or client (jmeter) side? What do you mean by "turn on" ?

Comment: I understood the question.  I provided a better source of data that is easier to process.   See w3c log options, specifically the time-taken field.